# Iterate through Pandas dataframe rows in a triangular fashion

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe *df* like this:

```
    col1.      col2
0.  value11    List1
1.  value12    List2
2.  value13.   List3
..  ...        ...
i.  value1i.   List_i
j.  value1j.   List_j
..  ...        ...
```

Col1 is the key (it does not repeat). Col2 is a list. In the end, I want a set intersection of each of the rows of Col2.

I would like to iterate through this dataframe in a triangular fashion.

Something along the lines of:

```
 for i = 0 ; i < len(df); i++
     for j = i+1 ; j < len(df) ; j++
         Set(List_i).intersect(Set(List_j)
```

So, 1st iterator goes through the full dataframe, while the second iterator, starts from one greater index than the 1st iterator and goes until the end of the dataframe.

How to do this efficiently and in a fast manner?

Edit:

Naive way of doing this is:

```
col1_list = list(set(df.col1))
num_col1_entries = len(col1_list)
for idx, value1 in enumerate(col1_list):
    for j in range(idx + 1, num_col1_entries):
       value2 = col1_list[j]
       list1 = df.loc[df.col1 == value1]['col2']
       list2 = df.loc[df.col2 == value2]['col2']
       print(set(list1).intersection(set(list2)))
```

Expected output: n(n-1)/2 prints of set intersections of each pair of rows of col2.

Comment: kindly post ur expected output. d triangular path is a must? besides, ur code does not look like python

Comment: In the end, I want to calculate the cosine similarity between each pair of lists in `col2`. Set intersection is the first step. Triangular path is desirable, but not a must.

Comment: I added a naive way of doing this. I want to avoid the use of `loc`.

Comment: no worries. kindly add ur expected output

Comment: @sammywemmy added expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `itertools`. Let's say this is your dataframe:

```
    col1.   col2
0   value11 List1
1   value12 List2
2   value13 List3
3   value14 List4
4   value15 List5
5   value16 List6
```

Then get al the combinations (15) and print the intersection between the two lists:

```
from itertools import combinations

for pair in list(combinations(df.index, 2)):
    print(pair)
    list1 = df.iloc[pair[0],1]
    list2 = df.iloc[pair[1],1]
    print(set(list1).intersection(set(list2)))
```

Output (only printing the pair):

```
(0, 1)
(0, 2)
(0, 3)
(0, 4)
(0, 5)
(1, 2)
(1, 3)
(1, 4)
(1, 5)
(2, 3)
(2, 4)
(2, 5)
(3, 4)
(3, 5)
(4, 5)
```

Comment: it works for me. Though, I did not need `tolist()`. They were already lists. I also changed `intersect` to `intersection`. Is `iloc` O(1)?

Comment: It is very fast as well. My `1406` rows finished in `45.6` seconds

Comment: Thanks, I fixed those two mistakes in the answer. I am not sure about iloc complexity. However, you can replace it with `iat`  that is a faster version of `iloc`.